# How to import modules in Swift's JavaScriptCore?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, ecmascript-6, javascriptcore

I'm trying to use Swift's JavaScriptCore framework to take advantage of an existing JavaScript library that uses ES6 modules. Specifically, [morse-pro](https://github.com/scp93ch/morse-pro) by Stephen C Phillips. I've added the files to an Xcode playground, then used this code to load the library and run it in the JavaScript context:

```
import JavaScriptCore
var jsContext = JSContext()
// set up exception handler for javascript errors
jsContext?.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
    if let exc = exception {
        print("JS Exception:", exc.toString())
    }
}
// read the javascript files in and evaluate
if let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "morse-pro-master/src/morse-pro-message", ofType: "js") {
    do {
        let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)
        jsContext?.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This approach works fine with simple "Hello world" sort of tests, but it chokes on the morse-pro library with this JavaScript error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '*'. import call expects
>   exactly one argument.

The error appears to be caused by this line in morse-pro-message.js:

```
import * as Morse from './morse-pro';
```

which I believe is trying to import all the morse-pro files as a module.

I'm not familiar with ES6 modules, but the library appears to be working for others in normal JavaScript contexts. Is there something wrong with the way I'm loading the library in Swift? Or are modules a feature that JavaScriptCore doesn't support? (The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) just says it supports "JavaScript" and doesn't get any more specific.)

I would appreciate any suggestions that point me in the direction of getting this library running in a JavaScriptCore VM.

Comment: dont know if it helps or not. try installing babel and transform your javascript files to es5

Comment: https://github.com/scp93ch/morse-pro contains only `src` which is ES6. It's very common to not commit `dist` to a repo. If you cloned it, it's expected that you will build it to ES5 by your own with `npm build`. To avoid that, install packages from NPM as a rule of thumb.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'import' is not correctly implemented in JavaScriptCore

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After much bumbling around in the dark, I found a way to make the library available to Swift without having to manually alter it.

First, as @estus suggested, I installed the library using NPM, which converts it to ES5 but does not resolve the dependencies. So it's still a bunch of separate files that call each other with `require` and `export` keywords that neither browsers nor JavaScriptCore understand.

Then I used [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to bundle all the dependencies into a single file so that JavaScriptCore could understand it. The normal operation of Browserify hides all the code, so I used the "--standalone" flag to tell it to make marked functions available. If you export the ES5 file directly, it creates a generic object and puts your exported functions under `.default`. I want them slightly more accessible, so I created a new file to list the exports and then ran Browserify on that. So for example, a file called "morse-export.js" containing:

```
module.exports.MorseMessage = require('./lib/morse-pro-message.js').default;
```

Then I run Browserify on it like this:

```
browserify ./morse-export.js --standalone Morse > ./morse-bundle.js
```

And include the morse-bundle.js file in my Swift code using `Bundle.main.path(forResource)`. Now I can access the MorseMessage class using `Morse.MorseMessage`, so back in Swift:

```
jsContext?.evaluateScript("var morseMessage = new Morse.MorseMessage()")
print(jsContext!.evaluateScript("morseMessage.translate('abc')"))
```

prints ".- -... -.-." as you would expect.

The downside of this is that you have to manually add whatever classes and functions you want exported to your export file. Still, this seems to be the simplest way to do it. If there's a better way, I would love to hear about it!

Comment: what is new Morse.MorseMessage() ?? could you please explain the js code

Comment: @mirhpedanielle I'm a little rusty on this so forgive inaccuracies. `MorseMessage` is a  [javascript class](https://github.com/scp93ch/morse-pro/blob/master/src/morse-pro-message.js) from Stephen Phillips's morse-pro. In this answer I used Browserify's `--standalone` flag to create a javascript object called `Morse` and attach MorseMessage to it, to make it easy to import into Swift's Javascript context. Once that's done (and the bundle is imported), `MorseMessage` works like any normal Javascript class.

Comment: thanks buddy!!.. but I have a doubts it necessary to create a bundle with bundle name .. and also calling jsContext.evaluateScript is not working

Comment: It worked for me. If you figure out a better way to do it without a bundle, please post an answer.

Comment: I am trying to use the external libray within the wkwebview. do i need to follow the same way ? or shall i just load the bundle.js file in the path . Please advice.

Answer (score 8):

While using `import` for modules is not possible.

You can support `require('path/filename');` syntax.

This is done by providing require as a function to JS. The `import` command is (unfortunately) too exotic to implement in the given restrictions of `JSContext`.

See the following implementations

## Objective-C.

```
@interface MyContext ()
@property JSContext *context;

@implementation MyContext

- (void) setupRequire {
    MyContext * __weak weakSelf = self;

    self.context[@"require"] = ^(NSString *path) {

        path = [weakSelf resolvePath:path];

        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Require: File “%@” does not exist.", path];
            weakSelf.context.exception = [JSValue valueWithNewErrorFromMessage:message inContext:weakSelf.context];
            return;
        }

        [weakSelf loadScript:path];
    };
} 

- (NSString *) resolvePath:(NSString *)path {
    path = path.stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath;
    return path.stringByStandardizingPath;
}

- (void) loadScript:(NSString *)path {
    NSError *error;
    NSString *script = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (error) {
        script = @"";
        NSLog(@"Error: Could not read file in path “%@” to string. (%@)", path, error);
        // Return void or throw an error here.
        return
    }

    [self.context evaluateScript:script];
}
```

This example is based on code in Phoenix https://github.com/kasper/phoenix

https://github.com/kasper/phoenix/blob/master/Phoenix/PHContext.m#L195-L206

## Swift 4

This example is based on code in CutBox https://github.com/cutbox/CutBox

```
import JavascriptCore

class JSService {

    let context = JSContext()

    let shared = JSService()

    let require: @convention(block) (String) -> (JSValue?) = { path in
        let expandedPath = NSString(string: path).expandingTildeInPath

        // Return void or throw an error here.
        guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: expandedPath)
            else { debugPrint("Require: filename \(expandedPath) does not exist")
                   return nil }

        guard let fileContent = try? String(contentsOfFile: expandedFilename) 
            else { return nil }

        return JSService.shared.context.evaluateScript(fileContent)
    }

    init() {
        self.context.setObject(self.require, 
                               forKeyedSubscript: "require" as NSString)
    }

    func repl(_ string: String) -> String {
        return self.context.evaluateScript(string).toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I too have same issue in accessing my own JS code, which uses 3 external libraries(Lodash, Moment and Moment-range).

Initially i have tried by importing all 4 .js files(1-My own file and 3-libraries) inside my app bundle. But when im trying like this its not worked. **I faced issue in place where i have imported those libraries inside my own JS code**.

**Workaround:**

At last i have copied and pasted all codes from those libraries codes inside my own code and imported only one .js file(my own file) inside my app. So in this case no need to import anything from any library. So my code worked successfully.

> **NOTE:** I am not sure whether my workaround is good approach or not. I just thought to register my issue and workaround which helped me.

**My code:**

```
lazy var context: JSContext? = {
    let context = JSContext()

    guard let timeSlotJS = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "app", ofType: "js") else {
        print("Unable to read resource file")
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let timeSlotContent = try String(contentsOfFile: timeSlotJS, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        _ = context?.evaluateScript(timeSlotContent)
    } catch {
        print("Error on extracting js content")
    }

    let _ = context?.evaluateScript("var console = { log: function(message) { _consoleLog(message) } }")

    // Print log messages
    let consoleLog: @convention(block) (String) -> Void = { message in
        print("Javascript log: " + message)
    }
    context?.setObject(unsafeBitCast(consoleLog, to: AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "_consoleLog" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)

    // Print exception messages
    context!.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
        print("JS Error: \(exception!)")
    }

    return context
}()

func accessingJSCode() {
    let timeSlotScript = "DigitalVaultTimeSlotAvailabilityFuntion({\"services\": \(services)}, {\"response\": {\"result\": {\"CustomModule1\": {\"row\":\(rowValue)}}, \"uri\": \"/crm/private/json/CustomModule1/searchRecords\"}});"
    print(timeSlotScript)
    let timeSlots = context!.evaluateScript(timeSlotScript)

    // Then here i parsed my output JSON from script.
}
```

Thanks!!